# Error when embed a collection of Forms in Symfony2

Tags: php, forms, symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm trying to embed a collection of forms in a symfony2 application. I have to simple entities : `Shop` and `Address` whith a Shop which has multiple address. I follow the [Symfony2 documentation](https://symfony.com/doc/current/form/form_collections.html) but I get the error :

> Neither the property "address" nor one of the methods "getAddress()",
>   "address()", "isAddress()", "hasAddress()", "__get()" exist and have
>   public access in class "AppBundle\Entity\Address". 500 Internal Server
>   Error - NoSuchPropertyException

It seems to me that it is trying to access the `address` preoperty of my `Address Entity`.

Here is my `Shop Entity`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;
use Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection;
use AppBundle\Entity\Address;
use UserBundle\Entity\Seller;

/**
 * Shop
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_shop")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\ShopRepository")
 */
class Shop
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="shopName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $shopName;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="description", type="text", nullable=true)
     */
    private $description;

    /**
     * @var string
     * @ORM\Column(name="ownerName", type="string", length=255)
     */
    private $ownerName;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="UserBundle\Entity\Seller", cascade={"refresh"}, fetch="EAGER")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=false, onDelete="NO ACTION")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $owner;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Address", mappedBy="shop")
     * @Assert\Valid()
     */
    private $address;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(
     *      min = 9,
     *      max = 10,
     *      minMessage = "Le numéro siret doit contenir 10 chiffres",
     *      maxMessage = "Le numéro siret doit contenir 10 chiffres"
     * )
     */
    private $siret;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Image")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(nullable=true)
     */
    private $image;


    public function __construct() 
    {
        $this->address = new ArrayCollection();
    }

    /**
     * Get id
     *
     * @return integer 
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set shopName
     *
     * @param string $shopName
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setShopName($shopName)
    {
        $this->shopName = $shopName;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get shopName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getShopName()
    {
        return $this->shopName;
    }

    /**
     * Set shopName
     *
     * @param string $description
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setDescription($description)
    {
        $this->description = $description;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get description
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getDescription()
    {
        return $this->description;
    }

    /**
     * Set ownerName
     *
     * @param string $ownerName
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setOwnerName($ownerName)
    {
        $this->ownerName = $ownerName;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get ownerName
     *
     * @return string 
     */
    public function getOwnerName()
    {
        return $this->ownerName;
    }

    /**
     * Set siret
     *
     * @param string $siret
     * @return Shop
     */
    public function setSiret($siret)
    {
        $this->siret = $siret;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get siret
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getSiret()
    {
        return $this->siret;
    }


    /**
     * Set address
     *
     * @param ArrayCollection $address
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setAddress(ArrayCollection $address)
    {
        $this->address = $address;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get address
     *
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Address
     */
    public function getAddress()
    {
        return $this->address;
    }

    /**
     * Set owner
     *
     * @param \UserBundle\Entity\Seller $owner
     *
     * @return Owner
     */
    public function setOwner(Seller $owner = null)
    {
        $this->owner = $owner;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get owner
     *
     * @return \UserBundle\Entity\Sellers
     */
    public function getOwner()
    {
        return $this->owner;
    }


    /**
     *
     * @param Image $image
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Shop
     */
    public function setImage(Image $image)
    {
        $this->image = $image;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function getImage()
    {
        return $this->image;
    }

}
```

Here is my `Address Entity`

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Entity;

use Doctrine\ORM\Mapping as ORM;
use Symfony\Component\Validator\Constraints as Assert;


/**
 * Adress
 *
 * @ORM\Table(name="app_address")
 * @ORM\Entity(repositoryClass="AppBundle\Repository\AddressRepository")
 */
class Address
{
    /**
     * @var int
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
     * @ORM\Id
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="street", type="string", length=255)
     * @Assert\Length(  min = 5 , 
     *                  max = 200,
     *                  minMessage = "L'adresse doit faire au minimum {{ limit }} caractères.",
     *                  maxMessage = "L'adresse doit faire au maximum {{ limit }} caractères.")
     * 
     */
    private $street;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=5)
     * @Assert\Regex(
     *     pattern="/^\d{4,5}$/",
     *     match=true,
     *     message="Le format n'est pas correct"
     * )
     */
    private $postalCode;

    /**
     * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true)
     */
    private $city;

    /**
     * @var string
     *
     * @ORM\Column(name="country", type="string", length=255 , nullable=true)
     * @Assert\Length(  min = 3 ,
     *                  max = 50,
     *                  minMessage = "Le pays doit faire au minimum {{ limit }} caractères.",
     *                  maxMessage = "L'adresse doit faire au maximum {{ limit }} caractères.")
     *
     */
    private $country;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Shop", inversedBy="address")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="shop_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $shop;

    /**
     * Get id
     * @return int
     */
    public function getId()
    {
        return $this->id;
    }

    /**
     * Set street
     *
     * @param string $street
     *
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setStreet($street)
    {
        $this->street = $street;

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get street
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function getStreet()
    {
        return $this->street;
    }

    /**
     * Set postalCode
     * @return Address
     */
    public function setPostalCode($postalCode)
    {
        $this->postalCode = $postalCode;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Get postalCode
     */
    public function getPostalCode()
    {
        return $this->postalCode;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Address
     */
    public function setCity($city = null)
    {
        $this->city = $city;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function getCity()
    {
        return $this->city;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param string
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Address
     */
    public function setCountry($country = null)
    {
        $this->country = $country;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function getCountry()
    {
        return $this->country;
    }

    /**
     *
     * @param Shop
     * @return \AppBundle\Entity\Address
     */
    public function setShop($shop = null)
    {
        $this->shop = $shop;
        return $this;
    }

    /**
     *
     */
    public function getShop()
    {
        return $this->shop;
    }

    public function __toString() {
        return $this->street." ".$this->postalCode." ".$this->city;
    }
}
```

I created two formType in order to manage my entities :

ShopType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\CollectionType;

use AppBundle\Form\AddressType;
use AppBundle\Entity\Shop;
use AppBundle\Entity\Address;

class ShopType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('shopName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom du magasin *', 'required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('ownerName', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Nom du gérant *', 'required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true))

            ->add('address', CollectionType::class, array(  'entry_type' => AddressType::class,
                                                            'allow_add' => true,
                                                            'label' => 'Adresse *', 
                                                            'required' => true
            ));
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => Shop::class,
        ));
    }
}
```

AddressType.php

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

use AppBundle\Entity\Address;

class AddressType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('address', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Adresse*', 'required' => true))
            ->add('CodePostal', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Code postal*', 'required' => true, 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('Ville', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Ville', 'required' => false, 'error_bubbling' => true))
            ->add('Pays', 'choice', array(
                    'choices'   => array(
                            'FR'   => 'France',
                            'SU'   => 'Suisse',
                            'BE'    => 'Belgique'
                    )
            ))
        ;
    }

    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
                'data_class' => Address::class,
        ));
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'addresse';
    }
}
```

In my controller, I'm instanciating my form as following :

```
$shop = $shopRepo->findOneByOwner($user);
if ($shop == null){
    $shop = new Shop();
}
$form = $this->createForm(ShopType::class , $shop);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is occurred due to this line at `AddressType` class:

`->add('address', TextType::class, array('label' => 'Adresse*', 'required' => true))`

You are trying to access `address` property of `Address` entity, but it doesn't contain it. The same is related to other fields: `CodePostal` => `postalCode` etc

Also at your `Shop` entity you have `address` field annotated as `OneToMany` relation which is ok, and at the same time you have `setAddress(ArrayCollection $address)` method, but instead you should have:

```
public function addAddress(Address $address)
{
    $this->address->add($address);

    return $this;
}
```

and optional

```
public function removeAddress(Address $address)
{
    $this->address->remove($address);

    return $this;
}
```

Btw I suggest to rename property `address` into `addresses` to highlight that it should contain collection but not single entity.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your explanation. I'm glad you "validated" my OneToMany relation, I was not sure about it. Also, thanks for correcting my Shop entity !